# Angular with CouchDB Cookie Authentication 401

Tags: angularjs, authentication, curl, cookies, couchdb

I would like to login into my Angular app with CouchDB cookie authentication.

The very first step is to make a admin account then try to CURL if cookie authentication works.

I post to curl

curl -vX POST 127.0.0.1:5984/_session -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -d 'name=foo&password=bar'

and this comes out

"https://i.stack.imgur.com/j23hU.jpg"

yes the username and password is correct

user was made from "SETUP ADMIN of Futon" (is there a different username and password i should be looking for?)

cors is enabled

origins set to *

Advance Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On screenshot take a look on the last line: `'password' is not recognizes as an external or internal command...`. On Windows you need to use double quotes to escape special characters, not single ones, or write `&` as `^&`.

Answer (score 0):

Not name but username.

```
curl -vX POST 127.0.0.1:5984/_session -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -d 'username=foo&password=bar'
```

Comment: My bad, doesn't know that with username it works too